# "Type name requires a specifier or qualifier" error

Tags: ios4

I have the following code but can't compile it because I have a "Type name requires a specifier or qualifier" error" for (self).

How to fix this error? I have compared it with the original code and there are no differences, so I don't know what's going on.

```
#import "CurrentTimeViewController.h"


@implementation CurrentTimeViewController

{
    // Call the superclass's designated initializer
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"CurrentTimeViewController" 
                       bundle:nil];

    if (self) {
        // Get the tab bar item
        UITabBarItem *tbi = [self tabBarItem];

        // Give it a label
        [tbi setTitle:@"Time"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Here is the code from the mirror file HynososViewController.h, and which I cut, pasted and modified:

```
#import "HypnososViewController.h"


@implementation HypnososViewController

- (id) init
{
    // Call the superclass's designated initializer
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil 
                       bundle:nil];

    if (self) {
        // Get the tab bar item
        UITabBarItem *tbi = [self tabBarItem];

        // Give it a label
        [tbi setTitle:@"Hypnosis"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle
{
    // Disregard parameters - nib name is an implementation detail
   return [self init];
}

// This method gets called automatically when the view is created
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Loaded the view for HypnosisViewController");

    // Set the background color of the view so we can see it
    [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
}
@end
```

Here is the complete code for CurrentTimeViewController.h:

```
#import "CurrentTimeViewController.h"


@implementation CurrentTimeViewController

{
    // Call the superclass's designated initializer
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"CurrentTimeViewController" 
                       bundle:nil];

    if (self) {
         // Get the tab bar item
         UITabBarItem *tbi = [self tabBarItem];

         // Give it a label
         [tbi setTitle:@"Time"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)Bundle
{
     // Disregard parameters - nib name is an implementation detail
     return [self init];
}

 // This method gets called automatically when the view is created
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Loaded the view for CurrentTimeViewController");

    // Set the background color of the view so we can see it
    [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
}



@end
```

Comment: is the error really in those lines of code ?

Comment: It is what's getting highlighted in xCode 4. Funny thing is that in another view controller which is exactly the same except for name of the nib and color there is no such problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the code above a cut-and-paste of EXACTLY what you are trying to compile? If so, I think you are missing something very important that would make that code block a method implementation:

```
-(id)init // This, or something like it, is missing???
{
    ...
}
```

Check your code, here, and in your project. :-)

Comment: Great. This is missing from what you originally pasted in: `- (id) init`. That is likely missing from the code you are trying to compile, which is generating the error you are seeing... I bet.